# how to show two textview side by side in android using constraint layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

My requirement is to show two `TextView` side by side in single line left side `textView1` with start margin 16dp and `textView2` right side with end margin as 16 dp both have top and bottom as 8dp. `textView1` is date like `Mar 30 2020 12:34 PM` and `textView2` is ref no like `ref no : 2144561237867219487387i948039463` length of 25 characters.

In small resolution screen, I need to show both `textView1` and `textView2` value completely without any ellipse kind of thing.

My current coding overlaps as `textView2` is 25 character length, so I'm looking for a solution like `textView1` should be shown completely followed by space in between and right side `textView2` and for small screen value should come some thing like below

`Aug 20 2020 15:748 pm`     on left side with 16 margin
`ref no:64635487265bwhjqgeyui6w5q7896wo67`   right side with 16 margin on right.

Is it possible to do like above?
Any idea is also appreciated!

In pixel 3, api 29, both `textView1` and `textView2` appear fine, but having problem in low resolution phones.

Below is my code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""                                        
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"                                        
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In high resolution phones, both `textView1` and `textView2` should be single line and if screen resolution differs, I need to achieve some thing like above  using constraint layout only.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How do you want them to occupy space? Do you want them together to fill the whole horizontal? Or you are planning on adding another View on the right of them?

Comment: i need some thing like below

Comment: aug 20 2020 4:56 pm                                                                                             ref no:
                                                                                                         
                                                                                                    364t2532676387564653

Comment: there should space between textview 1 and 2 , textview 1 start margin as 16dp and textview 2 end margin as 16dp

Comment: for textview 2 ref no: in line 1 and value in next line end only for low resolution screens

Comment: Just use 2 linear layouts

Comment: both textview value should be shown completely without ellipse and may be textview 2 in two line how to achieve this?

Comment: need to achive this in constraint layout only

Comment: Okay I will try to aswer that!

Comment: I have tested your code and your layout textviews are side by side already. How do you want it add a picture please.

Comment: example textview 1 : Aug 20 2020 13:56 pm on left side  and ref no: value on right side if small resolution screen ref no text on complete right side  line 1 and value should appear in next line right side end with margin 16 dp

Comment: ref no value is like 25 characters check my above code in low resolution screen

Answer (score 2):

Try this Code :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
   android:id="@+id/layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="32dp"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
       android:text="Aug 20 2020 4:56 pm"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView2"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
       android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Ref no: 364t2532676387564653"
       android:gravity="end"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView1"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What it will do is the first `TextView` will take only required space it needs to show the date. Then, second `TextView` will be on its right side but its height can vary in case complete text takes multiple lines. As you've stated that text should wrap in next line in small-screen sizes, this will wrap the text `Ref no: 364t2532676387564653` partially in next line so the complete text stays visible without using ellipses(`...`). I've not tested this as I wrote it here but I'm sure it will work.

Comment: can android:layout_marginStart="16dp" in textview can be avoided, since i need ref no: at right side end only and value same right side end in next line can this be done?

Comment: textview 1 and textview 2 should not be inter connected both at left and right end only

Comment: @vijilily You can add `android:gravity="end"` in `textView2` so that the text will always be shifted to right side making more gap in between the two `TextView`. Apart from that, the interconnection between the `TextView` is to prevent overlapping and wrap the text to next line in case phone size is small. That you've to do to prevent it.

Comment: complete value can be shown in next line keeping ref no text in line 1 and value starting from next line 2 end is it possible to do like this in one textview when screen resolution is low?

Comment: i need some thing like this
ref no: in line 1
T325675689578436t67574y8o357y8i76234 in line 2